# Unable to install Laravel Homestead - UID/Directory issue

Tags: php, laravel, virtualbox, homestead

I have followed the steps on Laravel's website, to install Homestead, through VirtualBox.

1. Install Virtual Box (through their package)
2. Install Vagrant (through their package)
3. Run `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
4. Within my application's directory, run `composer require laravel/homestead --dev`
5. Run `php vendor/bin/homestead make`

All of the console output shows a success for the above. I can see the `Homestead.yml` and `Vagrantfile` files within the app's directory.

When I run `vagrant up`, I then get this error:

> The VirtualBox VM was created with a user that doesn't match the
>   current user running Vagrant. VirtualBox requires that the same user
>   be used to manage the VM that was created. Please re-run Vagrant with
>   that user. This is not a Vagrant issue.
>
> The UID used to create the VM was: ** Your UID is: **

I'm unsure why this has happened, as I haven't used sudo, nor switched between.

Also, within Virtual Box's preference, it shows the default install location of boxes to be in: `/Users/AccountName/VirtualBox VMs`, but that directory doesn't exist.

However, Vagrant will list `laravel/homestead` as a box that's installed.

I'm unsure what exactly the problem is.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to run *vagrant up* command into ~/Homestead directory.